# rails-ujs is required, but not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

`application.js` requires:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= stub ./sign
```

Clearly, `rails-ujs` is required in the same manner it is in the default config. I'm including this in the layout template with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>`
```

In one of my views, I have the following code, which sets the method to delete.

```
<%= link_to 'delete',
  announcement_path(announcement),
  method: :delete,
  data: {
    confirm: 'Are you sure?'
  }
%>
```

This is properly rendered, with `data-method='delete'` being present on the link. Upon clicking that, it performs a `GET` request (visible in the logs).

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious. No errors appear in the console, and the `rails-ujs` file is *not* requested (per the network tab in the dev console).

Worth noting this is entirely local, not on a third party server.

Comment: Have you tried to add `//= require jquery` on the top of all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to the following

On the Gemfile

```
 gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

Then

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
#=> remove this line //= require rails-ujs
```

Make sure the restart your server after installing `gem`

[jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

Hope to help

Comment: `jquery` isn't found. I'm 99% sure `rails-ujs` is meant to be there, since it is there when I create a new project.

Comment: Ok fine I have updated answer follow this one @jhpratt

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Any idea why that wouldn't be included by default?

Comment: I don't know but in the rails, as usual, it's included by default when creating the project

Comment: Got me. Just tried a new project and it's not in the Gemfile. Regardless, now I know what I have to do when I create a new project :)

Comment: I know this answer works but it does not solve the rails_ujs problem, you are just dropping the built-in support and going back to JQuery. The reason that Jquery is no longer in the Gem file is because Rails core turned to rails_ujs instead. I am going to look further into this, I just ran a new rails project and I am geting this same issue. From what I belive this should work without Jquery.